# Inserting text at begining of each line of text file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a task to enter word http:// at begining of each line of text file. How this can be done using shell script

My text file is like:

```
agr.nc.in
mpi.ni.in
ir.o.in
chemis.go.in
da.ni.in
dgt.go.in
dgn.go.in
```

output file should be like:

```
http://agr.nc.in
http://mpi.ni.in
http://ir.o.in
http://chemis.go.in
http://da.ni.in
http://dgt.go.in
http://dgn.go.in
```

Comment: The regex for "beginning of line" is `^`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sed:

```
$ echo -e 'foo\nbar\nbaz'
foo
bar
baz
$ echo -e 'foo\nbar\nbaz' | sed 's|^|http://|'
http://foo
http://bar
http://baz
```

Answer (score 1):

to edit in place with sed:

`sed -i 's|^|http://|' infile`

to do it with shell only:

`while read LINE || [ "$LINE" ];do echo "http://$LINE";done <infile >outfile`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$0="http://"$0' your_file
```